# Superset export_datasources doesn't work

Tags: python, sqlite, apache-superset

I wanted to export/import datasources from CLI and I saw this too comands on superset:

```
superset export_datasources
superset import_datasources
```

but when I try to use `export_datasources` it gives me the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: dbs [SQL: u'SELECT... nFROM dbs']`
```

I don't understand how to fix it, maybe I miss some configuration (set a path or I don't know)

Comment: I don't have that query on the code.

Answer (score 0):

This feature tracked by follow issue: https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/pull/3978

and released in version 0.21.0 (2017/12/08 09:11 +00:00)
be sure your Superset version is not older than this.